# my website date show me time 06:00 instead of 18:00

Tags: php, time

im using this code too show now time in my website:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran'); echo date('h:i:s'); ?>
```

but with this code show me 06:00 instead of 18:00
please help me how to i can change this code to edit this problem.

Comment: You should try the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
h   12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
```

Use `H` not `h`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this-

```
echo date('H:i:s');
```